# Using Import for PIP Installed Packages While Using Kivy on Windows

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I am trying to use the Python module [pyowm](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm) with [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) and am having problems getting the import statement to work. I am on Windows 8.1 and downloaded pyowm using PIP. When I try and use "import pyowm" and then send the file to Kivy.bat it says "No module named pyowm" but when I just run a program that uses only pyowm from command line it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The kivy portable package includes its own python, but it sounds like you have installed pyowm into some other python installation.

I haven't used the windows package, but I think somewhere in it there should be a way to run its internal pip. If nobody responds here, someone on the kivy mailing list or irc probably knows.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to launch the kivy-34.bat file and use its PIP "PIP install pyowm"